# Solution needed for C# form serial port hang due to serial port reception and multi-threading

Tags: c#, multithreading, forms, serial-port

Im actually kind of stuck here in this small piece of application.

It's actually meant to read serial port data which comes at the rate of 1Hz from a hardware and update it on the two graphs and data gridview in the main form. The first form actually auto-detects your serial port and awaits you to click next and proceed to the application. In case it is not able to detect your serial port it throws an error.

After reaching the main form, you'll have to press the start button to start the serial port reception. The hardware actually sends a three digit number in the format, "100\n 200\n 300\n...." for every one second interval. The two graphs and the Datagridview on the tabs above updates every time a new data enters in.

Since, one second is too short of an interval to update the two graphs, update datagridview, compare the input value to some alert settings,etc., the application was multi-threaded. The graph update method was split into a separate thread and even the serial port data reception is handled by data_received event which is also by default a separate thread.

But, here's the problem, the application runs well in debug mode. However, when I run it after publishing, the serial data reception alone hangs after some random time interval. I believe this is due to some data misinterpretation or multi-threading time allowance issue or something. I would be really greatful if someone could figure out what the problem is.

I have affixed my source code. Feel free to use it for your applications also. In case the app shows error on visual studio. Please include Zedgraph.dll into your form controls from the debug or release folder.

[Click here for entire Application in zip file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/21341671/Voltage_Logger%28Backup%2012.5%29.zip)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: We don't do unzipping from links here.

Comment: 'The graph update method was split into a separate thread' doesn't sound promising:(

Comment: Feel free to use source code where the only one fact we have at hand is that it doesn't do what it's supposed to do. Erm... nah. But thanks anyway

Comment: Before the graph update method was split into a separate thread, the UI was responding very slow. Only when I split it up, it was working normal. There is a way to solve this simple two-thread app. I just need to know where it went wrong and what causes the serial reception failure after a while when running after deploying / publishing

Comment: It works properly in Debug mode @daveL . The least you can do is run it and then comment whether it works or not.